# Downloading an entire firebase storage folder's content in Unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

Hello im trying to download an entire folder's content from firebase into an android device.

The firebase hierarchy looks like the following:
[image]

So far I can only download a single file using the following code:

```
// ------------------------- FILE DOWNLOADING ------------------------------------- //
Debug.Log("Download Attempt...");

if (Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite))
{
    Debug.Log("STEP1...");
    //Firestore Reference
    storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
    storageReference = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://houdini-ac884.appspot.com");
    StorageReference riversRef = storageReference.Child("uploads/3895d968-65bf-4e2d-a964-763e22742fdf.meta");
    //StorageReference 
    //pathReference = storage.GetReference("uploads/3895d968-65bf-4e2d-a964-763e22742fdf.meta");
    // Create local filesystem URL
    Debug.Log("STEP2...");
    var Directory_path = ("SparseSpatialMap/" + "3895d968-65bf-4e2d-a964-763e22742fdf.meta");
    var path = (Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + Directory_path);   
    Debug.Log("STEP3...");
    // Download to the local filesystem
    //pathReference.GetFileAsync(path).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => 
    //{
    riversRef.GetFileAsync(path).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => 
    {
        if (!task.IsFaulted && !task.IsCanceled) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Finished downloading...");
            easyar.GUIPopup.EnqueueMessage("Download Completed", 5);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("DOWNLOAD FAILURE !!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
            easyar.GUIPopup.EnqueueMessage("FAIL EXCEPTION", 5);
        }

        Debug.Log("STEP4...");
    });
} 
else 
{
    Debug.Log("No Permissions");
    easyar.GUIPopup.EnqueueMessage("FAIL, No permissions", 5);
    Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite);
}

Debug.Log("End of Download Attempt...");
// ------------------------- FILE DOWNLOADING END ------------------------------------- //
```

From what I understand there isnt a firebase function to download all files in folder and I would have to use something else.
Any help would be apreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a REST API to get the metadata information of all the files present inside a folder.

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/o?preifx=path/to/folder
```

The param passed to the above API is the path to the folder.

First you need to get a list of files present in a folder. The below method gets a list of file:

```cs
async Task<List<FileMetadata>> GetFilesInFolder(string path)
{
    const string baseUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/";
    const string projectId = "PROJECT_ID";

    // Build the REST API URL
    string url = $"{baseUrl}{projectId}/o?prefix={path}";

    // Send a GET request to the URL
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
        // Read the response body
        string responseText = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // Deserialize the JSON response
        ListFilesResponse responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListFilesResponse>(responseText);

        // Return the list of files
        return responseData.Files;
    }
}
```

After you get the list of metadata of the files, start downloading each of them.

```cs
List<FileMetadata> files = await GetFilesInFolder(folderPath);

// Download each file
foreach (FileMetadata file in files)
{
    // Get the file's download URL
    string downloadUrl = file.DownloadUrl;

    // Download the file using the URL
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(downloadUrl))
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
       
        byte[] fileData = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

        // Save the file to the device
    
    }
}
```

Also do add the response objects from Firebase's endpoints

```cs
class ListFilesResponse
{
    public List<FileMetadata> Files { get; set; }
}

// Class that represents metadata for a file in Firebase Storage
class FileMetadata
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DownloadUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Any ideia what should I be importing to  "FileMetadata"? Getting :Type or namespace could not be found, and i havent figured it out yet.

Comment: So FileMetadata is a class that  we have to define, so that during de serialization of the response JSON, we can convert it into a C# class. You can find the definition of the class at the end of the answer.

Comment: [This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata#file_metadata_properties) are the properties that a fileMetada object can hold. In the code, I am just storing the essential properties, but you are free to store more.